# Vim less.sh settings won't import properly

Tags: vim, less

On my system, I've aliased less to vim's less.sh macro (let's call it vless). For some reason, this macro doesn't fully import the line-highlighting settings in my .vimrc .

vless turns on highlighting, but uses underlining instead of bg+bold. In comparison, vim does exactly what I want. See pictures below. How do I fix this?

vimrc in vim:
[image: vimrc in vim]

Same file in (v)less:
[image: vimrc in less]

Comment: Most likely less.sh is overriding what you are putting your vimrc. Try putting the highlight line in the after directory. (You might also try [vimpager](https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager) which seems to be a succesor to less.sh)

Comment: There is also a replacement of `less.sh` called `vimpager` which is configured by means of its own rc file. It might be worth a glance: https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager

Comment: It seems that less.sh does indeed flush my highlight settings by calling `syntax on` again, through less.vim. <br/>


Since vimpager is a portable shellscript I can run anywhere, I'm going to call that the answer. Fixing the less.sh script requires elevated access, and would be slightly more tedious than using a new pager script.

Thanks @FDinoff and @user1146332!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`vimpager`](https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager) which is the successor to `less.sh`.

---

If you actually wanted to change the highlighting after less.sh did its own highlighting you could create the file `~/.vim/after/colors/<colorscheme_name>.vim` with the following contents.

```
hi CursorLine term=bold cterm=bold ctermbg=Black
```

This should be sourced after less.sh does its own configuration.